# Binary classification with pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I wrote a simple neural network binary classification algorithm using Pytorch. It uses the dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/pritsheta/heart-attack, which consists of a table with 300 rows and 14 columns. The final column, 'target', is the training goal and indicates whether this patient has a hearth disease.

I define two classes, CustomDataset and NeuralNet. The CustomDataset modifies the data into Pytorch tensors. This is done by standardizing the columns containing quantities and one-hot-encoding the columns containing categorical data.

The NeuralNet class represents a fully connected neural network with a hidden layer and a sigmoid function at the end.

Furthermore, the function get_accuracy() gets the fraction of correctly predicted labels. Finally, I create a loop that trains the neural network and plot the losses and accuracies.

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,Dataset,random_split
from torch import Generator,nn
import torch
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,file):
        """
        Reads the csv with data and converts it to tensors. There are 3 types of columns:

        self.cols_standardize : Columns for which the values will be standardized
        self.cols_binary: Columns with binary values
        self.cols_ohe: Columns with categorical data. Will be converted to one hot encoding
        """

        self.data = pd.read_csv(file)

        #Set colums to take into account
        self.cols_standardize = ['age','trestbps','chol','thalach','oldpeak']
        self.cols_binary = ['sex','exang','fbs']
        self.cols_ohe = ['cp','restecg','slope','ca','thal']

        #Create empty tensor
        ohe_num_classes = self.data[self.cols_ohe].nunique().values
        self.x_cols_num = len(self.cols_standardize) + len(self.cols_binary) + ohe_num_classes.sum()
        self.x = torch.empty((len(self.data),self.x_cols_num), dtype=torch.float64)

        #Add standardized values
        means = self.data[self.cols_standardize].mean()
        stds = self.data[self.cols_standardize].std()
        x_std = (self.data[self.cols_standardize] - means)/stds
        self.x[:,:x_std.shape[1]] = torch.from_numpy(x_std.values)
        current_col = x_std.shape[1]

        #Add binary values
        x_bin = self.data[self.cols_binary]
        self.x[:,current_col:current_col+x_bin.shape[1]] = torch.from_numpy(x_bin.values)
        current_col += x_bin.shape[1]


        #Add ohe values
        ohe_data = torch.from_numpy(self.data[self.cols_ohe].values.astype(np.int64))
        for i,num_classes in enumerate(ohe_num_classes):
            x_ohe = nn.functional.one_hot(ohe_data[:,i],num_classes)
            self.x[:,current_col:current_col + x_ohe.shape[1]] = x_ohe
            current_col += x_ohe.shape[1]

        #Set target value to tensors
        self.y = torch.Tensor(self.data['target'].values)



    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        return self.x[idx], self.y[idx]


class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    """
    Neural network with one hidden layer and a sigmoid function applied to the y_logits
    """
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size):
        super(NeuralNet,self).__init__()

        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,1)
        self.out_layer = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self,x):
        out = self.layer1(x.float())
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.out_layer(out)
        return out


def get_accuracy(y_true,y_prob):
    """

    :param y_true: True values for y
    :param y_prob: Estimated values for y
    :return: Accuracy of estimation
    """
    y_estimate = y_prob > 0.5
    return (y_true == y_estimate).sum() / y_true.size(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    #Set parameters
    learning_rate = 10e-3
    num_epochs = 25
    weight_decay = 10e-5
    batch_size=32
    hidden_layers = 10

    #Create dataset
    dataset = CustomDataset('data.csv')

    #Split dataset into train and test data
    train_split = 0.8
    train_len = round(train_split*len(dataset))
    train_data,test_data = random_split(dataset,[train_len,len(dataset)-train_len],generator=Generator().manual_seed(0))


    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)
    test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_data,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)

    #Create model
    model = NeuralNet(dataset.x_cols_num,hidden_layers).to(device)

    criterion = nn.BCELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate,weight_decay=weight_decay)

    #Train model
    accs = []
    losses = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch ',epoch)
        for i, (x,y) in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            model.train()

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            yhat = model(x)
            loss = criterion(yhat[:,0],y)

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        losses.append(loss.item())


        #Get accuracy
        with torch.no_grad():
            x_test = test_data[:][0]
            y_test = test_data[:][1]
            y_pred = model(x_test)[:,0]
            acc = get_accuracy(y_test,y_pred)
            print(f'test set accuracy: {acc}')
            accs.append(acc.item())

    #Plot results
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(accs)
    plt.plot(losses)
    plt.legend(['test set accuracy','loss'])
```

Since this is my first time working with Pytorch, i'm quite sure there are many suggestions for improvement and everything is welcome. However, I am particularly interested in the following:

- **Machine learning wise improvements**: I know there are probably many things to improve on this and my goal is not to build the perfect predictor. However, are there any standard things that basically everyone with a bit of experience would add, that I seem to be missing?
- **Conventions/standard coding/rookie mistakes**: Are there any things that I am doing that are considered obsolete/stupid/overly complicated?
- **Code structure**: I create 2 classes and 1 function. Does this seem oke as a structure, or is something else recommended?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!